# Конструкция If,else в цикле for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Даны числа от 1 до 31 включительно

```
a = input().split()
q=0
x = [ print(i, end=' '), q=q+1 for i in z if int(i)%2==0 ]
```

Если число `i` четно, то выведи его и прибавь к перемемнной  `q+1`

Но при компиляции выводит ошибку:

in: 4 16 19 31 2
out:

```
x = [print(i, end=' '), q=q+1 for i in z if int(i)%2==0]
                         ^    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Зачеееем Вы так отформатировали код? Это ужасно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers = [i for i in range(1, 32, 1)]

numbers = [[i for i in numbers if i % 2==0], [i for i in numbers if i % 2!=0]]

print("Чётные числа: {0}".format(numbers[0]))
print("Нечётные числа: {0}".format(numbers[1]))
```

*Или так*

```
numbers = [i for i in range(1, 32, 1)]

numbers = [[print("Чётные числа: {0}".format(i)) for i in numbers if i % 2==0],\
           [print("Нечётные числа: {0}".format(i)) for i in numbers if i % 2!=0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
q = 0
for i in a:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
        print(i, end=' ')
        q += i
print(q)
```

Comment: Я знаю, что таким методом можно сделать, но я хочу минимализировать код.
Устал бесконечно так выстраивать код

Comment: @NappySays Вам привели так, как надо. За Ваши минимизации Вас будут бить, потому что так использовать `list comprehension` неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = [int(i) for i in a if int(i)%2==0]
print(sum(x)) # сумма четных чисел
print(x) # список четных чисел
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input().split()
q = 0
x = [print(q+1) for i in a if int(i) % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Но у вас же q в итоге никак не обновляется